# Check if list contains only item x

Tags: python, list

Say all of w, x, y, and z can be in list A. Is there a shortcut for checking that it contains *only* x--eg. without negating the other variables?

w, x, y, and z are all single values (not lists, tuples, etc).

Comment: Are w,x,y and z all single values or lists?

Comment: @SteveMayne All single values.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "all single values", do you mean things like `int` and `float` and `str`ings, or could (e.g.) `y` be a `list`?

Comment: @DSM Yup, I mean the int/float/str.

Comment: Wait- do you mean that it doesn't include w, y, or z but can include other variables (let's say a, b, or c?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson No--it can _only_ include x.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
A=[w,y,x,z]
all(p == x for p in A)
```

Comment: Be careful: if list is empty, the expression always evaluates to `True`- although `x` is not in the list. If the list may be empty, use `all(p == x for p in A) and len(A) > 0`

Comment: Would be helpful if you could make in an example with both Lists, I can't understand that code at all

Answer (score 21):

That, or if you don't want to deal with a loop:

```
>>> a = [w,x,y,z]
>>> a.count(x) == len(a) and a
```

(`and a` is added to check against empty list)

Comment: I found this method to be 5 times faster than the accepted answer.

Comment: Very cool, pythonic answer. And apparently faster too.

Comment: does this really work? it returns fales.

Answer (score 5):

This checks that all `element`s in `A` are equal to `x` without reference to any other variables:

```
all(element==x for element in A)
```

Comment: I think it can include multiple x's

Answer (score 5):

If all items in the list are hashable:

```
set(A) == set([x])
```

Comment: this is a bit inefficient as you have to compute the set instead of just iterating through `A` once

Comment: In newer versions you can use `{x}` sugar.

Answer (score 4):

```
{x} == {w,x,y,z} & set(A)
```

This will work if all of `[w,x,y,z]` and items in `A` are hashable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what *without negating the other variables* means, but I suspect that this is what you want:

```
if all(item == x for item in myList): 
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres another way:

```
>>> [x] * 4 == [x,w,z,y]
```

of the many already stated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two interpretations to this question:

First, is the value of x contained in [w,y,z]:

```
>>> w,x,y,z=1,2,3,2
>>> any(x == v for v in [w,y,z])
True
>>> w,x,y,z=1,2,3,4
>>> any(x == v for v in [w,y,z])
False
```

Or it could mean that they represent the same object:

```
>>> w,x,y,z=1,2,3,4
>>> any(x is v for v in [w,y,z])
False
>>> w,x,y,z=1,2,3,x
>>> any(x is v for v in [w,y,z])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach that works for a list with hashable items and also handles empty lists.

```
len(set(A)) == 1
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient solution, but I think it is quite readable and scores well at Code Golf :)

Some examples:

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1]
len(set(A)) == 1
>>> True

A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
len(set(A)) == 1
>>> False

A = []
len(set(A)) == 1
>>> False

A = [(1,), (1,), (1,), (1,)]
len(set(A)) == 1
>>> True

A = [[1,], [1,], [1,], [1,]]
len(set(A)) == 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```