# Why do Numpy.all() and any() give wrong results if you use generator expressions?

Tags: python, numpy

Working with somebody else's code I stumbled across this gotcha. So what is the explanation for numpy's behavior?

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: foo = [False, False]

In [3]: print np.any(x == True for x in foo)
True  # <- bad numpy!

In [4]: print np.all(x == True for x in foo)
True  # <- bad numpy!

In [5]: print np.all(foo)
False  # <- correct result
```

p.s. I got the list comprehension code from here: [Check if list contains only item x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222706/check-if-list-contains-only-item-x)

Comment: These are not technically list comprehensions, rather generator expressions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy all differing from builtin all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391501/numpy-all-differing-from-builtin-all)

Comment: This is a real "gotcha" for people using ipython's "pylab mode", which overwrites the built-in any and all with the numpy any and all. So you can have a code snippet that works in pure python but fails in pylab mode.

Comment: @SteveB That is exactly what happened to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`np.any` and `np.all` don't work on generators. They need sequences. When given a non-sequence, they treat this as any other object and call `bool` on it (or do something equivalent), which will return `True`:

```
>>> false = [False]
>>> np.array(x for x in false)
array(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x31193c0>, dtype=object)
>>> bool(x for x in false)
True
```

List comprehensions work, though:

```
>>> np.all([x for x in false])
False
>>> np.any([x for x in false])
False
```

I advise using Python's built-in `any` and `all` when generators are expected, since they are typically faster than using NumPy and list comprehensions (because of a double conversion, first to `list`, then to `array`).

Comment: the documentation is quite vague.. `Input array or object that can be converted to an array.` but still, the way I interpret it, it should work with generators...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: the `array` docstrings spells it out: "An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence." This is the definition of "array-like" used throughout NumPy. Unfortunately, any *other* object is converted to 0-d array (try `np.array("foo").shape`).