# Python return success if all values in the list are 40

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list which contains looks like the following:

```
lst = [40, 40, 40, 40]
```

I would like to print success only if all the values in the list are 40, else failure. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
if(len(set(lst))==1)
   print("Success")
else:
   print("Failure")
```

This prints success but it also prints success if all the values in the list are [1,1,1,1].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if all elements of a list match a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-match-a-condition), alternatively change your condition to: `len(set(lst))==1 and lst[0] == 40` (i.e., check there's only 1 unique value, and that value is 40)

Comment: `set(lst)=={40}`

Comment: Also a closer duplicate of [Check if list contains only item x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222706/check-if-list-contains-only-item-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin function `all()` to check each element. And using python's ternary `if else` you can make it into a one liner

```
print('Success' if all(v==40 for v in lst) else 'Failure')
```

Answer (score 1):

Small modification:

```
if len(set(lst)) == 1 and 40 in lst:
   print("Success")
else:
   print("Failure")
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be an Example for your problem:

```
lst = [40, 4, 40, 40]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if (lst[i] == 40):
        success = True
    else:
        success = False
        break

print(success)
```

Answer (score 1):

`set(lst)` will give you a container in which each element of `lst` occurs only once. If every element is 40, then the set will contain 40 and nothing else.

So you can check

```
if set(lst)=={40}:
   ...
```